# How to resolve out of memory issue

Tags: android

Friends i am working on a application which containing so many images and animations.Due to which after running the application 2,3 times it is crashing automatically and the log cat is showing out of memory issue. What will be the solution?

Comment: The solution would probably be something along good memory management, load only what you need, unload what you can, null out references fast etc. You're running in a garbage collected VM, but there's a lot of good ways to help it conserve memory.

Comment: No one could possibly answer this question specifically without a lot more detail, sample code, etc.  Please re-ask the question with more specifics, and we'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: As from the beginning i have clarified that my app containing lots of images and audios, for which it was showing memory crash, But thanks for all your support,I came out with the solution.

Answer (score 7):

It would be best to create a class that extends Application .
This application class will give you onlowmemory() callback whenever application goes low memory. 
on there you can write

```
public void onLowmemory()
{
          Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
```

which will invoke system GC method. Upon executing garbage collector android will garbage all unused objects.

There is another way to solve this problem. In animation you can call Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
to invoke garbage collector. also in activity onDestroy() method u can call  Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

so your problem will be solved