# android out of memory error

Tags: java, android, spring, web-services, out-of-memory

I'm calling RESTFUL API. I'm using spring libraries. But I'm getting this OutOfMemoryError when restTemplate.exchange is executed. Below is my code snippet and error log.
I'm using this code to get data from the server using webservices. On some  devices this works fine but few devices throws exception.

```
    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo(mContext);

        map.add("organizationId", "0");
        map.add("groupCode", securityCode);
        map.add("deviceId", deviceInfo.getDeviceID());
        map.add("version_code", deviceInfo.getVersionCode() + "");
        map.add("freshDataLoad", mode);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        String respStr = responseEntity.getBody();
```

following is the error log

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:189)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToString(FileCopyUtils.java:240)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:107)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:44)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:98)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:728)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:504)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:452)
at com.example.testapp.sync.SyncStrategy.getTestData(SyncStrategy.java:
at com.example.testapp.sync.SyncWorker$2.run(SyncWorker.java:126)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: What are the differences in memory spec. between devices where it works and other where it doesn't? The jvm might need memory extension or so.

Comment: Maybe response is just too big. Try to load data by parts or use streams.

Comment: On a micromax tab it works fine but on a samsung tab it throws error both the tabs have 1GB RAM and 1.3GHz processor

Answer (score 0):

This may happens as your application consumes a lot of memory.
Try to optimize your application code.

Also, a trick may helps you : try to call garbage collector explicitly before handle this request, which requires a lot of memory.

Call:   Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); to invoke garbage collector.

Refer to link:
[How to resolve out of memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228594/how-to-resolve-out-of-memory-issue)